# Remake page while loading

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension for chrome. The problem is I need to insert an iframe of loading page into DOM instead of loading itself.

Here is a code of the content script which is not working:

```
window.stop();
var body = document.createElement("body");
body.src = window.location.href;
document.documentElement.appendChild(body);
```

Why browser generate body in DOM but don't show it on the page?

Comment: You're adding it to the documentElement (usually the <html> tag), not the body

Comment: It doesn't metter what I am append. There are no body (when I'm appending body with background color nothing happens too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have got no idea why is it happen, but window.stop blocks the DOM from changes after calling. In order to reset this state I should do this:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = "";
```

And as a bonus head and body will be appended automatically)